# Button click on HomePage shows SplashScreen after OnSleep app

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am having a hard time with a buggy behavior in a client app, so I tried to reproduce it on a sample at GitHub. Sometimes when minimize the app and reopen it, it is getting stuck in SplashScreen after clicking a HomePage button that goes to a NavigationPage.

Steps to reproduce:

- On Debug mode, start the app and click the "Go to Tabs" button at HomePage
- When done use Android Home button to minimize the app - OnSleep (do not swipe to close completely)
- Re-open the app and you are going to see the HomePage again
- Click the "Go to Tabs" button and get stuck at white SplashScreen

Here I give a sample to reproduce the bug:
https://github.com/nilomobrj/xf-buggy-sample/tree/main/Tab

Also uploaded a video to demonstrate:
https://youtu.be/9ZlPYznG9zE

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Your code looks no problem , and I can't be able to reproduce the issue by following the steps. I have doubt about the step 3 , shouldn't it show Tab page after re-open the app ?

Comment: Hello! It is supposed to show the HomePage when reopening the app instead the tabs page. I do not know why, but it just happens in debug mode, meanwhile in the client app he told it is happening sometimes. When I try the app without debug on, it works the way you have mentioned.